# Como salvar valor corretamente no SharedPreferences? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, graphql

Olá, pessoal!

Onde estou errando?

Tenho login com google para pegar o token e enviar para o graphgl. Este token é salvo - pelo menos era o que deveria ser - no sharedpreferences, mas não está salvando. Tenho a seguinte action (mobx).

```
@action
Future loginWithGoogle() async {
 user = await _authRepository.getGoogleLogin();
 final idToken = await user.getIdToken();
 print('Bearer ${idToken.token}');
 sharedPreferenceService.setToken('Bearer ${idToken.token}');
}
```

**Services shared.**

```
class SharedPreferenceService {
  SharedPreferences _prefs;

  Future<bool> getSharedPreferencesInstance() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().catchError((e) {
      print("shared prefrences error : $e");
      return false;
    });
    return true;
  }

  Future setToken(String token) async {
    await _prefs.setString('token', token);
  }

  Future clearToken() async {
    await _prefs.clear();
  }

  Future<String> get token async => _prefs.getString('token');
}

SharedPreferenceService sharedPreferenceService = SharedPreferenceService();
```

Action para login na view.

```
@action
  Future loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      loading = true;
      await auth.loginWithGoogle();
      Modular.to.pushReplacementNamed('/index');
    } catch (e) {
      loading = false;
    }
  }
```

O login acontece normal mas acusa erro quando vai para index, informando que recebeu nulo o ***getString("token")***.

```
I/flutter ( 3198): ClientException: Unhandled Failure NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getString' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 3198): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 3198): Tried calling: getString("token")
```

Esta string token não está sendo salva.

Answer (score 1):

Corrigindo...

Retorna vazio sem ainda não foi gravado nada.

```
Future get token async => (await _prefs.getString('token')) ?? '';
```

Comment: Corrigi a action
`
@action
  Future loginWithGoogle() async {
    user = await _authRepository.getGoogleLogin();
    final idToken = await user.getIdToken();
    print('Bearer ${idToken.token}');
    bool value = await sharedPreferenceService.getSharedPreferencesInstance();
    if (value == true) {
      sharedPreferenceService.setToken('Bearer ${idToken.token}');
    }
  }`